# For the POV of latency/cpu usage Which is good SharedPreferences or SQLite android

Tags: android, performance, android-sqlite

Assuming I have a small ~200 item keyvalue pair Array. What should I use a SQLite or SharedPreferences.

Say I wish to store an array of tuples {X,Y} for a TAG t, I save the preference as TAG: X1,Y1;X2,Y2;..

The pre and post processing is to convert it into/from a ArrayList.

If I use a DB would I be better off in terms of CPU utilization and latency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276358/pros-and-cons-of-sqlite-and-shared-preferences) that might help you, especially Tom's answer. I vote for SharedPreferences in your case as long as you keep your key names small (i.e. T1, T2, ... Tn) and the total number under 200. Furthermore there is another [thread here with measurements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076444/explain-perf-difference-in-accessing-sharedpreferences-on-different-android-devi) as you can see writing 100 integers may take from 1 second up to 8 seconds on some devices which may trigger an ANR error if you do it in the UI thread, so consider using background thread for this kind of tasks.

Hope this helps...